# BeautifulSoup returns empty list - other parsers are causing Python to error

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm sure this is pretty close to a lot of other SO posts but I'm having trouble tailoring those questions and answers to the problem I'm seeing.

BeautifulSoup is returning `[]` when I run the code shown below. I have been searching for information on SO and saw this article talking about parsers and known bugs: [Html parsing with Beautiful Soup returns empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821789/html-parsing-with-beautiful-soup-returns-empty-list). But when I try other parsers I get an error:

```
Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml.
```

I am using Python 2.7.10 on a Macbook Pro. Does anyone know of a way to get a different parser to work? Or even if the parser is the problem? The site itself does not assign class names to `div` tags so below is just an attempt to return something.

```
import urllib2, base64, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = urllib2.Request("http://www.oklahomacounty.org/assessor/Searches/AN-R_HistoricalView.asp?Accountno=R120682380")
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.read(), 'html.parser')
div=soup.findAll('div')
print div
```

Comment: `Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml.` - that error sounds like you just don't have `lxml` library installed.

Comment: If the website doesn't assign any `div` classes why do you expect it to return something rather than an empty list?

Comment: The site uses `div` tags, but there is no `class name` attribute used inside the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is reporting no `<div>` tags on the page because there *are* no `<div>` tags on the page.  If you actually look at the contents of the URL in question, you see:

```
<html>
<head>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=2977d8d74f63d7f8fedbea018b7a1d05">
</script>
<script>
(function() { 
var z="";var b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for (var i=0;i<b.length;i+=2){z=z+parseInt(b.substring(i, i+2), 16)+",";}z = z.substring(0,z.length-1); eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+z+')'));})();
</script></head>
<body>
<iframe style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" src="//content.incapsula.com/jsTest.html" id="gaIframe"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

There are no `<div>` tags here; the page contents are generated through some combination of JavaScript and an iframe.  You will need far more than just BeautifulSoup if you want to scrape this site.